# Disabling SSL check on OAuth calls (PHP)

Tags: php, ssl, oauth

I'm pretty new to php so this might be a noob question.

I'm using this [library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) to make oauth-signed requests, but I'm getting a problem with the ssl certs. I need to bypass the certificate validation (I **know** this is a security problem, it's for development only).

I've found this function:

```
http://php.net/manual/en/oauth.disablesslchecks.php
```

Which looks exactly what I need but when trying to run the code with this:

```
OAuth::disableSSLChecks();
```

I get this error:

```
[Fri Dec 17 15:43:12 2010] [error] [client ::1] PHP Fatal error:  Class 'OAuth' not found in /Library/WebServer/Documents/oauth/test.php on line 9
```

Any ideas why this is happening ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you have the OAuth PECL library installed.  You can tell if it's installed by producing a phpinfo().

Comment: @Andrew I've installed it doing `pecl install oauth`... still failing though. Any ideas?

Comment: @Pablo have you restarted apache after installation?

Comment: @Andrew yes I did. Do I need some 'include' stuff?

Comment: There shouldn't be a need for an include, except if directory with OAuth files is not in you include path. Check it with `get_include_path()`. Oh, and I generally don't care how people call me, but just to let you know, my name is not Andrew :)

Comment: @David, hehe sorry for that I confused you with the guy who answered. :) will check the include_path, thanks!